# Question about the univalence axiom versus skeleta.

Tags: category-theory, philosophy, foundations

[Here](http://homotopytypetheory.org/2013/03/08/homotopy-theory-in-homotopy-type-theory-introduction/), Dan Licata writes:

> [Univalence] can be used to build algebraic structures in such a
>   way that isomorphic structures are equal (e.g. equality of groups is
>   group isomorphism).

He writes something similar [here](http://homotopytypetheory.org/2011/07/27/canonicity-for-2-dimensional-type-theory/):

> A consequence of the univalence axiom is that isomorphic types are
>   equivalent (propositionally equal).

Now [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/skeleton) writes:

> A category is skeletal if objects that are isomorphic are necessarily
>   equal; so this is a notion irredeemably violating the principle of
>   equivalence of category theory.

Is there not a contradiction here? How can we claim that:

1. skeletons violate the principle of equivalence
2. univalence upholds it

when apparently, univalence implies that every category is skeletal?

Comment: My impression is that the meaning of equality is strengthened in homotopy type theory, so it doesn't mean what it usually means.

Comment: I'd call it "weakened", not "strengthened". There are more equalities, not fewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, Homotopy Type Theory introduces some *extraordinary* equality, which approach requires special attention, and so the n-Lab article is a little bit out of this context, as it uses categories *over some classical set theory*, while HoTT defines its own 'precategories' and 'categories'.

For a motivating example, when we arrange four small balls in $2\times 2$ matrix, we give an interpretation of the multiplication $2\times 2$ of numbers, but *as a number* this arrangement *equals to* $4$:
$$2\times2\ =\ 4 $$
Similarly, we might want that e.g. the Klein group $V_4$ and the product group $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ would be *equal, as groups* (independently of exactly which four elements build them and how).
$$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\ =\ V_4$$

As you have found, categories --as defined in HoTT-- are indeed necessarily *skeletal* in that setting.

1. That '*Skeletons violate the principle of equivalence*' refers to the fact that the property 'skeletal' is not invariant under category equivalence.
2. As every category (in the sense and context of HoTT[!]) is skeletal, category equivalence here seems to coincide to *category isomorphism*, hence -by Univalence- to *equality*. 
   In HoTT the notion 'skeletal' just gets meaningless.

But the whole HoTT theory is still under development, terms and definitions are not necessarily in their finalized form yet..

Comment: I mean, its still not making a lot of sense. If we're using a set-theoretic foundations, then we can just add "skeletal" to the definition of "category." And then viola, skeletality is invariant under category equivalence. But we've cheated, of course; by including skeletal in our definition of category, we've ensured that pretty much every category that occurs in nature is in fact not a category. How is univalence any better than this?

Comment: @user18921, with your definition of category, Grp would not be a category, while it is a category in the sense of HoTT.  Don't you find that "better"?

Comment: @Adeel, by "group" I can just mean what is usually meant by "group isomorphism type." So Grp is now a category.

Comment: @user18921, well, this is not the only reason for HoTT, let's say only that this (more or less intuitive) concept seems to fit nicely in HoTT. Nevertheless, if *your only goal* is to build a theory when isomorphic things are actually equal, you are free to work in the wide land of strictly skeletal categories (over ZFC, say).